# load custom fields on click

Tags: custom-field, ajax

I have too much data stored in custom fields which I don't want to fetch on page-load, instead I'd give the user the opportunity to load the custom field values on click, possibly with ajax.

Is there a working way to do this?

I don't have any code yet just the wp loop. I'm thinking about putting the custom field queries in a separate php file, but I have no idea how to make connection between single.php and the separate file. (loading the file with ajax is no problem.)

UPDATE:
I don't need ajax, it's just confusing me so far. I just want to display the custom fields associated with the post on a different page template. I think of it as if the custom fields would be "children" of a given post and clicking a link would load a page with just the custom fields on it.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to use the ajax capabilities provided by WordPress. Your question is a little broad. Take a look at the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) and let me know if anything specific is unclear.

Comment: Also, check out a very similar question I answered yesterday which gives you a basic intro to WordPress and AJAX.  [AJAX & WordPress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32841/how-to-correctly-load-wordpress-in-a-non-wp-script-for-ajax-request/32843#32843)

Comment: Thanks. I'm afraid I don't quite understand this part of the codex... Updating my question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you've found an answer on this question yet since it's from 2011 but I have an idea on how to retrieve the data.

What if you created a VERY simple php file that took the post ID as a get variable and displayed the post's custom fields?

It would look something like this:

```
<?php
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php');
    $post_ID = $_GET['id'];

    $custom = get_post_custom($post_ID);

    foreach ($custom as $key => $value) {
        if (($key != '_edit_lock' && $key != '_edit_last'))
            echo '<tr><td>' . $key . '</td><td>' . $value[0] . '</td></tr>';
    }
?>
```

This will create a table of name (Custom Field Name) and value (Custom Field Value). If you don't want to use a table, of course you can format the internal bits however you want. I'm just trying to set you on the right track. Also, notice that there's an `if` statement in there. I'm sure you don't want to output the edit lock value or the last edit value.

Now, on to how to get this information from the page:

First, you'll need to create a button that will show the information.

```
<a href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/custom-field-provider.php?id=<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" class="show-more">See More Information</a>
```

And a box to show what you're going to AJAX in:

```
<div id="more-information-box" style="display: none;"></div>
```

You'll want to make up some cool little jQuery goodness here.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.show-all').on('click', function (e) {
        // Since we're already passing the data through the link, we don't need to do anything else. Just pull the url from the link.
        var url = $(this).attr('href');

        // A simple jQuery.get function to get the data from the php script we wrote earlier
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $('#more-information-box').hide().empty().append(data).fadeIn(500);
        });

        // And stop the link from actually going to the page.
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;  // Better safe than sorry, right?
    });
});
```

And that should do it for you.

I know it was a bit long-winded, but I really wanted to cover all the bases. I hope this helped you out.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, yes, I did something very similar although not that sophisticated. I'm in a middle of something right now and later today I your code a go.

Comment: You should use WordPress's [built in AJAX handling](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) rather than manually including `wp-load.php`.